# Search in MegaMenu Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor, mouseevent, megamenu

My company has a MegaMenu on their internal web portal. One of the popup menus has a Search input field which works fine. The problem is that when someone types in the input field and the mouse pointer moves off of the megamenu it, of course, disappears. I need to keep that popup menu open/visible while the user enters the search parameters. Whatever they typed is also invisible until they mouse over the menu item again. Also I am not sure if I should look at onfocus attribute, cursor positioning or a mousemove event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to opt for show/hide on click rather than toggle on hover. So that unless user does not wish to make that hide it is open. As it is convenient for users.